# Value matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django. I recently came across a problem: When I am trying to fetch objects, it is saying

```
DoesNotExist: Value matching query does not exist.
```

I searched the web but still I got no clue as to why this is happening.

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Value(models.Model):
eq_input = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='x**2 + y**2')
color = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Magma')
```

My forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Value

class ViewForm(forms.ModelForm):
Equation = forms.CharField(max_length=20, label='Equation')
Color = forms.CharField(max_length=20,label='Color')
class Meta:
    model = Value
    fields = {
        'Equation',
        'Color'
     }
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Value
from .forms import ViewForm

def home_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ViewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
       form = ViewForm()
       context = {
             'form': form
             }
return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

My home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>3D Graph Plotter</title>
</head>
<body>
   <center><h1>This is a 3D plotter</h1></center>
   <center>
   <form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" name="Save" />
    </form>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

and my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from equation.views import eq, home_view

urlpatterns = [
         path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
         path('', home_view, name='hv')
     ]
```

Is there something I am missing or something is wrong there? Can you point that out?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is inside your forms.py try this

```
from django import forms
from .models import Value

class ViewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Value
        fields = ['eq_input','color']
```

and if you want to add label

```
class Value(models.Model):

    eq_input = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Equation', default='x**2 + y**2')
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Color' ,default='Magma')
```

after that do not forget to run makemigrations and migrate.